# The derivative of $\sin \theta$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

I am a high school student and am reading derivatives for the first time.

In my book , before the topic of derivatives of trigonometric functions we were given a relationship between $\cos \theta$ and $\sin \theta$ which was :

$\cos \theta$ $< \frac{\sin \theta}{\theta}$ ; $ 0 < \theta < \frac{π}{2}$ , $\frac{-π}{2} < \theta< 0$

When I reached the topic of derivatives I came to know about this relationship between the two

$\frac{d(\sin \theta)}{d\theta} = \cos \theta$.

These two relations have confused me now. I want to know why is there a difference in the relationship between these two trigonometric functions
(similarly for other trigonometric functions too) once when seen at infinitesimal scale and the other at macroscopic scale ? Which one of these are true for any scale considerations ?

Shouldn't the relationship be this way

$\cos \theta ≤ \frac{\sin \theta}{\theta}$  ; ?

Help me with these.

Comment: Have you seen the two functions' respective Maclaurin series? Taking those as your definitions should be enlightening

Comment: There is no $\frac{\sin \theta}{\theta}$ in the derivative equation.

Comment: Just to check, $\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\theta}\neq \frac{d(\sin(\theta))}{d\theta}$

Comment:  We have $$\cos(2\pi)>\frac{\sin(2\pi)}{2\pi}$$

Comment: $\frac {sin \theta}{\theta}$ has nothing to do with with derivative $\frac {d\sin \theta}{d\theta}$.  The derivative is a limit, not an actual fraction and the $d$ is not and constant that you multiple that can be canceled out.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "microscopic" or "macroscopic" scale over here. The $\sin$ function has a particular definition that you would've encountered. Likely, it was the unit-circle definition that you learnt. From that definition, you can show that:

$$\cos(\theta) \leq \frac{\sin(\theta)}{\theta}$$

whenever $\theta \in (-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}) \setminus \{0\}$. In a similar manner, there is a formal way of specifying what we mean when we say that:

$$\frac{d}{d\theta} \sin(\theta) = \cos(\theta)$$

In particular, the thing on the left-hand side has a formal definition that can be used to prove that the equality above holds. So, there's no "macroscopic" or "microscopic" thing going on here.

These are very likely geometric intuitions you have about these relations that you should keep in the back of your mind but not dwell on too much. You can look at the pretty pictures and diagrams to get a bit of an idea. That's the imprecise blah blah blah.

I would actually suggest working through a Calculus book or an Analysis book. An enthusiastic high school student can certainly read such books. I personally used Modern Calculus and Analytic Geometry by Richard Silverman to learn about this stuff but I have heard that Calculus by Michael Spivak is also pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac {sin \theta}{\theta}$ has nothing to do with with derivative $\frac {d\sin \theta}{d\theta}$.  The derivative is a limit, not an actual fraction and the $d$ is not and constant that you multiple that can be canceled out.

$\frac {d\sin \theta}{d\theta} = \lim\limits_{\Delta \theta \to 0} \frac {\Delta \sin \theta}{\Delta \theta}=\lim\limits_{\theta_2-\theta_1\to 0}\frac {\sin \theta_2 -\sin\theta_1}{\theta_2-\theta_1}=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac {\sin(\theta+h) - \sin (\theta)}h$

So notice you are *not* dividing that $\theta$ at all ever.

To continue with our calculations:

$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac {\sin(\theta+h) - \sin (\theta)}h=$

$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac {\sin \theta \cos h + \cos \theta \sin h - \sin (\theta)}h=$

$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}[\cos\theta \frac {\sin h}{h} + \sin(\theta)\frac {\cos h- 1}h]=$

$\cos \theta \cdot 1 + \sin \theta \cdot 0=\cos \theta$.